# Ringing an extension Node.js SIP implementation

Tags: javascript, protocols, sip, rfc

I am attempting to create my own barebones SIP implementation.

Currently, I am just trying to ring another phone for initial testing purposes, while I work on the structure of my program. As you can see in the code, after successfully registering (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293864/node-js-asterisk-authentications-sip-udp-headers)), I send an `INVITE` request (as shown above). However, I am not receiving a `180 RINGING` response, which, according to the RFC, is what I should expect. I have tried using both the extension number and the SIP user's name, but to no avail. Do I actually need SDP to ring another extension? Could the issue lie not in the above SIP message, but possibly elsewhere in my implementation?

Here is the complete code snippet for reference:

```js
const dgram = require("dgram");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const asteriskDOMAIN = "";
const asteriskIP = "";
const asteriskPort = "";
const clientIP = "";
const clientPort = "";
const username = "";
const password = "";
let callId;

const generateBranch = () => {
  const branchId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
  return `z9hG4bK${branchId}X2`;
};

const generateCallid = () => {
  const branchId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
  return `${branchId}`;
};

const Parser = {
    parse: (message) => {
        const lines = message.split('\r\n');
        const firstLine = lines.shift();
        const isResponse = firstLine.startsWith('SIP');
      
        if (isResponse) {
          // Parse SIP response
          const [protocol, statusCode, statusText] = firstLine.split(' ');
      
          const headers = {};
          let index = 0;
      
          // Parse headers
          while (index < lines.length && lines[index] !== '') {
            const line = lines[index];
            const colonIndex = line.indexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex !== -1) {
              const headerName = line.substr(0, colonIndex).trim();
              const headerValue = line.substr(colonIndex + 1).trim();
              if (headers[headerName]) {
                // If header name already exists, convert it to an array
                if (Array.isArray(headers[headerName])) {
                  headers[headerName].push(headerValue);
                } else {
                  headers[headerName] = [headers[headerName], headerValue];
                }
              } else {
                headers[headerName] = headerValue;
              }
            }
            index++;
          }
      
          // Parse message body if it exists
          const body = lines.slice(index + 1).join('\r\n');
      
          return {
            isResponse: true,
            protocol,
            statusCode: parseInt(statusCode),
            statusText,
            headers,
            body,
          };
        } else {
          // Parse SIP request
          const [method, requestUri, protocol] = firstLine.split(' ');
      
          const headers = {};
          let index = 0;
      
          // Parse headers
          while (index < lines.length && lines[index] !== '') {
            const line = lines[index];
            const colonIndex = line.indexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex !== -1) {
              const headerName = line.substr(0, colonIndex).trim();
              const headerValue = line.substr(colonIndex + 1).trim();
              if (headers[headerName]) {
                // If header name already exists, convert it to an array
                if (Array.isArray(headers[headerName])) {
                  headers[headerName].push(headerValue);
                } else {
                  headers[headerName] = [headers[headerName], headerValue];
                }
              } else {
                headers[headerName] = headerValue;
              }
            }
            index++;
          }
      
          // Parse message body if it exists
          const body = lines.slice(index + 1).join('\r\n');
      
          return {
            isResponse: false,
            method,
            requestUri,
            protocol,
            headers,
            body,
          };
        }
    },

    getResponseType: (message) => {
        var response = message.split("\r\n")[0];
        if(response.split(" ")[0].includes("SIP/2.0")){
            return response.split(" ")[1];
        }else{
            return response.split(" ")[0];
        }
        return response;
    }
}

class Builder{
    constructor(context){
        this.context = context;
        return this;
    }

    register(props){
        if(props.realm && props.nonce && props.realm != "" && props.nonce != ""){
            return {
                'Via': `SIP/2.0/UDP ${clientIP}:${clientPort};branch=${generateBranch()}`,
                'From': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>;tag=${generateBranch()}`,
                'To': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>`,
                'Call-ID': `${this.context.callId}@${clientIP}`,
                'CSeq': `${this.context.cseq_count['REGISTER']} REGISTER`,
                'Contact': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${clientIP}:${clientPort}>`,
                'Max-Forwards': '70',
                'Expires': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Node.js SIP Library',
                'Content-Length': '0',
                'Authorization': `Digest username="${this.context.username}", realm="${props.realm}", nonce="${props.nonce}", uri="sip:${this.context.ip}:${this.context.port}", response="${this.DigestResponse(this.context.username, this.context.password, this.context.realm, this.context.nonce, "REGISTER", `sip:${this.context.ip}:${this.context.port}`)}"`
            }
        }else{
            return {
                'Via': `SIP/2.0/UDP ${clientIP}:${clientPort};branch=${generateBranch()}`,
                'From': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>;tag=${generateBranch()}`,
                'To': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>`,
                'Call-ID': `${this.context.callId}@${clientIP}`,
                'CSeq': `${this.context.cseq_count['REGISTER']} REGISTER`,
                'Contact': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${clientIP}:${clientPort}>`,
                'Max-Forwards': '70',
                'Expires': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Node.js SIP Library',
                'Content-Length': '0'
            }
        }
    }

    invite(props) {
        if(props.realm && props.nonce && props.realm != "" && props.nonce != ""){
            return {
              'Via': `SIP/2.0/UDP ${clientIP}:${clientPort};branch=${generateBranch()}`,
              'From': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>;tag=${generateBranch()}`,
              'To': `<sip:${props.extension}@${this.context.ip}>`,
              'Call-ID': `${this.context.callId}@${clientIP}`,
              'CSeq': `${this.context.cseq_count['INVITE']} INVITE`,
              'Contact': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${clientIP}:${clientPort}>`,
              'Max-Forwards': '70',
              'Expires': '3600',
              'User-Agent': 'Node.js SIP Library',
              'Content-Length': '0',
              'Authorization': `Digest username="${this.context.username}", realm="${props.realm}", nonce="${props.nonce}", uri="sip:${this.context.ip}:${this.context.port}", response="${this.DigestResponse(this.context.username, this.context.password, this.context.realm, this.context.nonce, "INVITE", `sip:${this.context.ip}:${this.context.port}`)}"`
            };
        }else{
            return {
                'Via': `SIP/2.0/UDP ${clientIP}:${clientPort};branch=${generateBranch()}`,
                'From': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${this.context.ip}>;tag=${generateBranch()}`,
                'To': `<sip:${props.extension}@${this.context.ip}>`,
                'Call-ID': `${this.context.callId}@${clientIP}`,
                'CSeq': `${this.context.cseq_count['INVITE']} INVITE`,
                'Contact': `<sip:${this.context.username}@${clientIP}:${clientPort}>`,
                'Max-Forwards': '70',
                'Expires': '3600',
                'User-Agent': 'Node.js SIP Library',
                'Content-Length': '0',
              };
        }
    }

    ack(){

    }

    BuildResponse(type, props){
        var map = {
            "REGISTER": this.register(props),
            "INVITE": this.invite(props),
            "ACK": this.ack(props),
        }
        return this.JsonToSip(type, map[type]);
    }

    JsonToSip(type, props){
        var request = `${type} sip:${asteriskDOMAIN}:${asteriskPort} SIP/2.0\r\n`;
        for(let prop in props){
            request += `${prop}: ${props[prop]}\r\n`;
        }
        request += `\r\n`;
        return request;
    }

    DigestResponse(username, password, realm, nonce, method, uri) {
        const ha1 = crypto.createHash("md5")
          .update(`${username}:${realm}:${password}`)
          .digest("hex");
      
        const ha2 = crypto.createHash("md5")
          .update(`${method}:${uri}`)
          .digest("hex");
      
        const response = crypto.createHash("md5")
          .update(`${ha1}:${nonce}:${ha2}`)
          .digest("hex");
        return response;
      }
}

class SIP{
    constructor(ip, port, username, password){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.Generator = new Builder(this);
        this.Socket = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
        this.callId = generateCallid();
        this.Events = [];
        this.cseq_count = {REGISTER: 1, INVITE: 1, ACK: 1}
        return this;
    }

    send(message){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.Socket.send(message, 0, message.length, this.port, this.ip, (error) => {
                if(error){
                    resolve({context: this, 'error': error})
                } else {
                    resolve({context: this, 'success':'success'});
                }
            })
        })
    }

    registerEvent(event, callback){
        this.Events.push({event: event, callback: callback});
    }

    listen(){
        this.Socket.on("message", (message) => {
            var response = message.toString();
            var type = Parser.getResponseType(response);
            if(this.Events.length > 0){
                this.Events.forEach(event => {
                    if(event.event == type){
                        event.callback(response);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }

    on(event, callback){
        this.Events.push({event: event, callback: callback});
    }

    start(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.listen();
            var test = this.Generator.BuildResponse("REGISTER", {})
            this.send(test).then(response => {
                if(!response.error){
                    this.on("401", (res) => {
                        var cseq = Parser.parse(res).headers.CSeq;
                        console.log(cseq);
                    
                        if(cseq == "1 REGISTER"){
                            const authenticateHeader = res.match(/WWW-Authenticate:.*realm="([^"]+)".*nonce="([^"]+)"/i);
                            if (authenticateHeader) {
                                this.realm = authenticateHeader[1];
                                this.nonce = authenticateHeader[2];                     
                                const registerRequestWithAuth = this.Generator.BuildResponse("REGISTER", {realm: this.realm, nonce: this.nonce});
                                this.send(registerRequestWithAuth).then(res => {
                                    
                                })
                            }
                        }else if (cseq == "1 INVITE"){
                            const authenticateHeader = res.match(/WWW-Authenticate:.*realm="([^"]+)".*nonce="([^"]+)"/i);
                            if (authenticateHeader) {
                                this.realm = authenticateHeader[1];
                                this.nonce = authenticateHeader[2];                     
                                const registerRequestWithAuth = this.Generator.BuildResponse("INVITE", {extension:"420", realm: this.realm, nonce: this.nonce});
                                this.send(registerRequestWithAuth).then(res => {
                                    
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })

                    this.on("200", (res) => {
                        //console.log(Parser.parse(res));
                        var cseq = Parser.parse(res).headers.CSeq
                        if(cseq.includes("REGISTER")){
                            console.log("REGISTERED")

                        }else if(cseq.includes("INVITE")){
                            console.log("INVITED")
                        }
                        this.cseq_count[cseq.split(" ")[1]] = this.cseq_count[cseq.split(" ")[1]] + 1;
                        resolve({context: this, 'success':'success'})
                    })

                    this.on("INVITE", (res) => {
                        //console.log(res);
                    })

                    this.on("NOTIFY", (res) => {
                        //console.log(res);
                        this.send('SIP/2.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
                    })

                } else {
                    resolve({context: this, 'error': res.error})
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

new SIP(asteriskIP, asteriskPort, username, password).start().then(res => {
    var invite_request = res.context.Generator.BuildResponse("INVITE", {extension: "420"});
    res.context.send(invite_request).then(res => {
        
    })
});
```

**UPDATE**
Upon examining the Wireshark SIP capture, I noticed that I am receiving a `401 Unauthorized` SIP message after sending the above `INVITE` request, even though I have successfully registered. This only occurs after sending the `INVITE` request. Do I also need to include the authentication header in my request?

Does Asterisk require something different? Additionally, I am observing constant retransmission of the same `NOTIFY` SIP message, even after sending `200 OK`. Although this might be irrelevant, I thought it would be helpful to mention it.

[Here](https://files.fm/f/bznx7q5ch) is a download for my Wireshark capture without sending the `INVITE` message. [Here](https://files.fm/f/v95bxfsqs) is a capture with the `INVITE` SIP message I'm not worried about people using it to log in to my PBX as it will be moved to another server and get a new IP and reconfigured entirely soon anyways so have fun.

**Update 2**

After some suggestions, Now I only send the `Authorization` header after I get a `401 Unauthorized`. I found that the `cseq` value can be used to differentiate `401` responses. After changing this I receive a new response, `482 Loop Detected`

**Update 3**
I noticed an error in my `INVITE` sip message. After changing the `Request-URI` to `sip:420@64.227.16.15:6111` I still get no changes.
Here is what my second `INVITE` message looks like after I add the `Authentication` header

```
INVITE sip:420@64.227.16.15:6111 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.2:6111;branch=z9hG4bK8777308828561X2
From: <sip:Rob@64.227.16.15>;tag=z9hG4bK1286583240470X2
To: <sip:420@64.227.16.15>
Call-ID: 4551011395608@192.168.1.2
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: <sip:Rob@192.168.1.2:6111>
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Node.js SIP Library
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: Digest username="Rob", realm="asterisk", nonce="1e5f4517", uri="sip:420@64.227.16.15:6111", response="85d378163c5e059ac3c9ee293d5e69d3"
```

I get this response in return

```
SIP/2.0 482 (Loop Detected)
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.2:6111;branch=z9hG4bK8777308828561X2;received=72.172.213.173;rport=41390
From: <sip:Rob@64.227.16.15>;tag=z9hG4bK1286583240470X2
To: <sip:420@64.227.16.15>;tag=as3e8a4d9d
Call-ID: 4551011395608@192.168.1.2
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 18.14.0~dfsg+~cs6.12.40431414-1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Hello! It's not clear if your question is about an outgoing call, and incoming call, or both. And it's a bit confusing because you have many questions! May be rewrite and list your exact question. It will be easier to make an answer!

Comment: Your first INVITE will usually have no authorization header. Then, you receive a new 401 or 407. Then, you send a second INVITE with the authorization header. (Same call-id, and increasing cseq like for the REGISTER). After this, you can expect the 180 ringing!

Comment: Awesome thank you for the help. Is there any way that I can figure out our contextualize what the 401 response is for? Currently, 401 triggers the REGISTER authorizations part. Is there a header or value sent back that could help me see that the 401 is a response to the invite I sent?. After doing some looking is this what the `cseq` parameter is for?

Comment: After some changes, I am receiving a new response now. I am getting a `482 Loop Detected` I'm not sure if this is a step forward but it seems to be. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: To match a 401 with a request, you mainly compare the *branch* of the Via. *482 Loop detected* means the server is forwarding the INVITE to himself, which probably means you use a wrong request-uri (first line of INVITE) domain: the server do not recognize himself.

Comment: So what would i use in the request uri instead of the PBX servers IP? Would i be using the extensions IP there instead? does SIP provide a mechanism to see registered clients if that is the case?

Comment: So your saying that I can match a request with the `branch` parameter of the `VIA` header? But currently, I regenerate it with every request. Should I only be generating a new one per dialogue? I guess i would store this in an array and the previous request to match 401's. If this is the case. I guess i'm misunderstanding what `CSEQ` is actually used for.

Comment: **branch** is used to match a response with a request (New for every **transaction**). **Call-id** and increasing **cseq** are used to consider 2 INVITE as part of the same **dialog**. Additionally, you need to consider **To tag** and **From tag** parameters to have those INVITE being considered as part of the same **SIP dialog**!

Comment: @AymericM Thank you for all of your help. If you would make an answer here I can mark it as answered. While your knowledge is insightful I am still confused what request-uri should I use for the invite request if I am not supposed to use my asterisk PBX URI? to avoid 482 loop detected. I feel i am very close to getting this working thanks to your help.

Comment: So the request URI i am using now for invites is `sip:${extension}@${asterisk_ip}:${port}` but i am still getting a `482 Loop Detected` I really am not sure what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you proposed, let's try to make an answer with all rules that you must follow for INVITE.

There are several topics involved when exchanging SIP message. Among them, let's discuss those specific elements:

- **Via branch**

Any new request needs a new Via branch. It needs to be random and always starts with the magic cookie *z9hG4bK*. It will always be copied in the SIP response for this request. Only retransmissions of SIP messages will have the same.

- **Authentication**

The initial REGISTER and the initial INVITE, using very basic implementation of Digest, will be sent without any **Authorization** or **Proxy-Authorization** header

After a 401 or a 407, Authentication is required. A new REGISTER (or INVITE) will be sent with the **Authorization** or **Proxy-Authorization** header.

- **Call-ID** and **CSeq**

When you start an application, you create a **Call-ID** for the initial REGISTER. Any new REGISTER, either for authentication or refreshing registration, will use the same **Call-ID** and will have an increased **CSeq**. This is ordering all successive transactions and help the server to follow the flow. It's a mandatory operation.

When you start a new call, you create a new **Call-ID** for the initial INVITE. Any SIP message within the same **SIP dialog** (same call)  needs to re-use the same **Call-ID** and will have an increased **CSeq**. Again, this helps ordering on remote side and is mandatory.

- **To tag** and **From tag**

The **From tag** helps to match all requests within the same **SIP dialog** (same call). It remains the same within call and is defined by the call initiator.

The **To tag** helps to match all requests within the same **SIP dialog** (same call). It remains the same within call and is defined/added by the call receiver. It's only known when a remote user first send a 1xx answer (like *180 Ringing*) or 2xx answer (like *200 Ok*).

- **Request-URI**

When a server receive (and accept) a request, it needs to decide if it will **forward to another operator** or **handle himself**. To make it clear, *Verizon* users are not in the database of *AT&T*, so if a call from *AT&T* to *Verizon* arrive on *AT&T*, it needs to forward to *Verizon*.

The same is happening in **Request-URI** with the *domain* of the SIP URI. If it's not recognize, DNS is used, and request is forwarded. However, if the request, using DNS is received again on same server, we can detect a loop and reject with **482 Loop Detected**

You may try to remove *port* from your *Request-URI*, or fix your *asterisk* config to *route correctly* your request. Don't know enough on *asterisk* to give a better hint.

*NOTE: might be better to be more specific in your future questions on stackoverflow. The perimeter was a bit too large on this question. Thanks.*

Comment: Thank you so much once again AymericM. My issue was a lot of things. But your explantation helped me understand it in a better way. The problem causing this turned out to be the `cseq` value not counting correctly. Thank you!